# Why is my cycles render generating these weird lighting glitches?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

https://youtu.be/CcjH_KlFI3A

Why is my rendering generating these weird flares and flashes?

I watched it render this and it literally rendered each frame perfectly 100% and then somehow glitched out at the very end and put the flares/glitches over the frame!

Any insight into what's going on and how I can fix it would be greatly appreciated!!

compositor
[image: here are nodes]

Comment: Can you please show your compositing screen

Comment: Yes I have added it ty

Comment: What format have you rendered to?

Comment: I've tried several, even just rendering those frames as .png comes out the same. it bakes the frame perfectly and then overlays either the flare or the glitchy white boxes :|

Comment: Does this also occur without the glare node?